# Can meters measure a distance in higher dimensions?

Tags: distance

Consider meters as a unit of measurement. Meters can, of course, be used to express distance across a two-dimensional plane. E.g. The distance from your chair to the door is 2 meters.

Meters can also be used in three-dimensions to express a distance throughout 3-axis, just as they can in one-dimension to express a distance along a single axis.

By this logic, do meters hold up as a valid unit of distance in higher dimensions?

Comment: The definition of the SI unit, "meter", is only meaningful in _physical_ space, but you can call the metric for any higher dimensional or lower dimensional metric space by any name you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes (although this is non-physical). Assuming that your extra dimensions are ones of distance, you're just adding another axis.

Maybe of interest to you would be googling "metric spaces" which are somehow generalizations of distance.

Answer (score 0):

Meter is a unit of distance, meaning that your extra dimension in which you want to measure has to be a dimension of space, also called a **spatial dimension**, if you want to use the unit meter.

There also are dimension of time. These are called **temporal dimensions**. Since meter isn't a unit of time, you can't measure anything in such a dimension with meter as your unit of measurement.

These are the only two dimensions in classical physics. In modern physics, there are **additional dimensions**. Those are any dimensions which are neither spacial nor temporal dimensions. Since, if you could measure them in meters, they'd be spacial and therefore not additional dimensions, you can't measure in meters in them either.